# Import data in SQLite (csv file) with a datetime field with 'now' value

Tags: sqlite, datetime, csv

I'm trying to fill a table through a csv file. One of my fields is a datetime to specify the time when the field has been created, so I would like to insert datetime('now') value...

Do you now how to create this field into the csv file?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

SQLite does not have separate [data types for dates/times](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime); date strings are just strings.

Furthermore, CSV does not really have data types; all fields are just read as is, and not interpreted in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.As it is just a script to initialize the table, I have updated the datetime field after executing the script (with an update sentence).